# Passing data by using bundle between tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment-tab-host

I am using Bundle to passing data from my First `TabFragment` but it prompts out with the `NullPointerException`. Error is occur when `getArguments()` in `list_fragments2` in second tab

**MainActivity Fragment**

```
list_fragment2 fragment = new list_fragment2();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("test","text");
fragment.setArguments(b);
Toast.makeText(this, "" + b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**SecondActivity Fragment**

```
 public class list_fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View h = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) h.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Bundle bundle=getArguments();

        //your string
        if(bundle != null) {
            String test = bundle.getString("test");
            textView.setText(test);
        }
            return h;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually load your second fragment?

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

list_fragment2 fragment = new list_fragment2();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("test","text");
fragment.setArguments(b);
fragmentTransaction.replace(placeholder, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: thanks , i try it before but i still get nullpointerexception this error

Comment: public class list_fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View h = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) h.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Bundle bundle=getArguments();

        //your string
        if(bundle != null) {
            String test = bundle.getString("test");
            textView.setText(test);
        }
            return h;

    }
}

Comment: Please edit your originial post with an "Update" section

Comment: Can't find an issue in `list_fragment2`. Can you post your current code of the `Mainactivity` too? Please update your original post again.

Comment: can i have i more question? is it possible to do it from Mainactivity tablayout using bundle pass data to tab fragment?

Comment: I don't even know your class structur. Normally you have a viewpager that provides swiping between the tabs. An adapter handles the loading of the tabs. And there you can pass a bundle too. You also can program manager classes/static variables or callbacks to pass/save information. If you have another question please open a new thread because you accepted this answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create your  instance of `list_fragment2` code within `list_fragment2`. Maybe your codes recreated list_fragment2 many times.

```
public static list_fragment2 createInstance() {
        list_fragment2 fragment = new list_fragment2();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle .putString("test","text");
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
```